# How to apply style to a confirm pop-up window

Tags: javascript

is it possible to give style to a confirm dialog box in javascript?

i am using asp.net with c#.

Eg:-
OnClientClick='javascript:return confirm("Are you sure, Do you really want to delete this item ")'

how to give style for this dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

The regular alert and confirm boxes are based on the window style currently applied to the operating system.

There are [replacements](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook_files/87/demo/) available though for the alert and confirm boxes. There are more than this one if you search for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery then take a look at

[jQuery Alert Dialogs (Alert, Confirm, & Prompt Replacements)](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook_files/87/demo/)

and

[Confirm Override](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/)